# Github.com will not load propery. Browser will not render images and media

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, browser, https

I'm having a real unique problem to Github.com

Here is a screengrab[image: screengrab]

I have tried:

1. Removing all browsing and cookies
2. Using a different browser (using chrome, but did same thing on Safari)
3. Reinstalling Chrome

It doesn't seem to be network related and specific to my computer/ip as my office mates can load it fine. Does anyone have any suggestions? where do I begin to look. This just started happening today.

So far I have found this unique to only github.com

UPDATE -
In the devel frame, I have these errors:

[image]

UPDATE RESOLVED -
My clock was set to march instead of february.

Answer (score 0):

if it is what I am experiencing I created a Chrome Extension for this read the only answer on [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685649/use-chrome-to-visit-github-can-not-load-css-and-js-but-ie-is-ok/40324786#40324786) I probably wont be able to answer the same question or it might mark my answer as a duplicate but i answered the question on the link theres a few other links that do that too but Its because google is stopping cross-origin loading the way github uses

---

Else it sounds like you should clear your cache or Images are disabled from loading to enable images in chrome look at the URL bar just right below your website tabs there should be a (i) icon on the left in that bar click it and press the dropdown Images and select "Always allow on this site"