# Use Chrome to visit github, can not load css and js. but IE is OK

Tags: google-chrome, github, cross-domain

my chrome version:50.0.2661.75 m
visit GitHub, can not load css and javascript
error:

```
CSS stylesheet from origin 'https://assets-cdn.github.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://github.com' is therefore not allowed access.
github.com/:1 Script from origin 'https://assets-cdn.github.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://github.com' is therefore not allowed access.
github.com/:1 CSS stylesheet from origin 'https://assets-cdn.github.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://github.com' is therefore not allowed access.
github.com/:1 Script from origin 'https://assets-cdn.github.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://github.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I test IE 11 and old version chrome(49.0.2623.112 m), it is ok.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this happened to me to so I created a Chrome Extension to fix that. Instructions to install it are below.

> ### How To Install The Extension

</>1. [Download This Free](https://bannerbomb-extensions.github.io/extensions/github_fix.crx)
2. Press the link to download the crx file
3. Type *chrome://extensions* in the URL box and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Open the location where the .crx file saved
5. Drag & Drop the .crx file into the *chrome://extensions* website
6. While you are hovering the .crx file in the website it will show Drop file here to install
7. Once you drop the .crx file it will show <kbd>Add extension</kbd> & <kbd>Cancel</kbd>
8. Press <kbd>Add extension</kbd>
9. Your Done
10. Now just goto [Github](https://github.com) and it should work with all the CSS/JS loaded.
The CSS/JS not loading is because I'm pretty sure that google is trying to stop Cross-Origin loading they said it was for security reasons. I'm not sure though but the extension I created will fix that on github... <strike>The extension has recently been made so im still trying to fix some of the bugs</strike>

---

**Update:**
Ok I just updated the extension I fixed the bugs now and it works perfectly I added a Automatic Update feature so when I update it it will automatically detect and update to the latest version. If it you can download the new version [Here](https://bannerbomb-extensions.github.io/extensions/github_fix.crx) you only need to download and install this extension once after that it will automatically update to the latest version if you want to manually update follow the instructions below

> ### How To Manually Update The Extension

</>1. Goto *chrome://extensions*
2. Look on the **Top Right** of the page
3. Check the box that says *Developer Mode*
4. Click <kbd>Update Extensions now</kbd> the button is located right **under** the checkbox that says *Developer Mode*
5. The extension is now updated.
*Enabling the Developer Mode Checkbox won't harm anything it just used for mostly extension/app developers*

---

If you don't want to enable the developer mode you don't have to but it will take a few hours for it to detect the updated version of the extension.

<strike>Sorry I'm trying to fix the extension again it stopped working</strike>

It is working for good now

---

**Last Update:** To update on this, The extension has not been updated in over 4 years and I am no longer maintaining it for future updates so it will not work anymore.

Comment: Hi, I am facing this same error but this extension seems broken.